# What control to create sms viewer in Symbian

Tags: sms, symbian, s60

I need to know what control I can use in Symbian to view SMS' or any text but seems like the one in Symbian S60 devices, to seem like the image below.

I'm going to use it in Symbian S60 5th Ed, Symbian^3 and Symbian Anna.

I'm coding with Symbian C++, Using Symbian S60 5th Ed SDK, And Carbide.C++ 2.7

[image]

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for this the best to use is the simple `CEikEdwin`. There are also other options for the rich text view, but believe me the `CEikEdwin` is more then sufficient.

If you have time you can override the virtual method `CreateCustomDrawL()` and provide your own `CLafEdwinCustomDrawBase` derived object. Then you can also underline the text lines like in regular SMS editor.

BR
STeN